# How to split a string with different signs and white spaces using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, match

I am trying to split this string:

```
bar .foo car.coo
```

to this array:

```
['bar',' .foo','car','.coo']
```

I have been trying variations on this phrase but I just can't seem to get it right:

```
str.replace(/([.#:])/g, '$1').split(" ");
```

The rules for the split is - if there is `[.#:]` then split - but if there is a whitespace before them (like `.foo`) then **include the white space**.

How do I do that?

Comment: Wouldn't the array become `['bar',' .foo car','.coo']`? There's no character between "foo" and "car" on which you want to split.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `"car.coo"` has to be splitted into two array elements without any character being consumed, `.split` is probably not what you want.

You can use `str.match`, which will form an array with the string parsed by the regexp:

```
"bar .foo car.coo".match(/( [.#:]|[.#:])?[^.#: ]+/g);
// ["bar", " .foo", "car", ".coo"]
```

Comment: great!! but can you explain what comes after the "?" in the expression? I get it that it is either " [.#:]" or "[.#:]" - but what comes next?

Comment: @Alon: The `[^.#: ]+` means "one or more characters that are not one of `".#: "`". This is needed because just e.g. `.+` would consume anything coming after it, including any special characters.

Answer (score 1):

`"bar .foo car.coo".match(/ ?.?\w+/g)` will return `["bar", " .foo", " car", ".coo"]`